# Repairing tile laid on harwood floor - how to make best of bad situation?

Tags: flooring, tile, hardwood-floor, hardwood, mortar

The previous owner of my house laid slate tile over hardwood in the entryway.  A 9 square foot area has become loose and I need to re-set the tiles.  Pulling everything out is not an option; I'm wondering how to make best of a bad situation.

Several products I've seen say specifically "don't apply directly to hardwood" (eg http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-133.pdf).  I'm wondering if using an appropriate primer first will make success more likely, such as CBP's Multi-Surface Bonding Primer (http://www.custombuildingproducts.com/TDS/TDS-115.pdf).  They describe it as "polymer-modified mortar ... for tiling difficult surfaces, such as plywood, vinyl and laminates, and for hard-to-bond, nonporous tile, such as porcelain and glass."

More generally, when a tile adhesive says "don't use directly on" hardwood or another surface is this because the product will perform poorly or because there could be unintended consequences (eg chemical reaction).

Comment: no on the chemical reaction part.

Comment: The surface you're attaching to is probably not the wood, but a polythene based varnish or finish.  One reason for failure may be different rates of expansion between the wood and the slate tile.  Thus, perhaps, an elastomeric compound will do a better (and yes, unconventional) job.

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't the finish of the wood, it is expansion and contraction. Wood moves a lot, even more so in entries. Only 2 options: take it out and use plywood over the wood and then tile, or keep making repairs.